# Python: Get mean and std dev from input using OOP

Tags: python, oop, statistics, mean

I have solved the following program to get mean and std dev from user's input, but I have the strong feeling that can be improved, mainly as I have to duplicate the split function, I had to do that because std_dev was using the mean result, so for that reason an error message was telling me that std_dev required at least two points.Here's my code, hope someone could help me out on this:The code uses "a" and "a_2" to avoid the problem above described:

```
import math
import statistics as st

class Data:
    def __init__(self, a, b)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.mean = st.mean(a)
        self.std_dev = st.stdev(a_2)

data_input = input("Enter data set:")
a = (float(x) for x in data_input.split(",")
a_2 = (float(x) for x in data_input.split(",")

data_1 = Data(a, 1.0)

print("Data mean is: %0.4f" %data_1.mean)
print("Standard Dev is: %0.4f" %data_1-std_dev)
```

Comment: `b` is never used. What inputs are you using?

Comment: yeah, I think I need to erase that. Input: 20, 40, 60 any set of numbers, the code actually works, is just that I think might be better done. I've erased "b" and works fine, just want to avoid the two split methods, I think it should work by using it once

Comment: `b` is never used, `data_1-std_dev` is not defined and also uses an illegal character ( - ) assume you meant `data_1.std_dev`,  `Data` class should receive both `a` and `a_2` rather than pulling from `global`. `a` and `a_2` are identical therefore `Data` could just receive either and calculate both from the input saving the time it takes to generate the second tuple ( Assuming the statistics module doesn't modify inplace ). As far as `OOP` focused, there's not much here to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that you are using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) with round parentheses to create an iterable of `float`'s and assigning it to `a`. So, `a` is a generator and is exhausted (empty) after you pass it to `st.mean()`. What you want is probably a list comprehension with square brackets, you will have a `list` that can be iterated as many times as you want.

```py
import statistics as st


class Data:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.mean = st.mean(data)
        self.std_dev = st.stdev(data)


data_str = input("Enter data set: ")
data_set = [float(x) for x in data_str.split(",")]  # note the square brackets
data = Data(data_set)
print(f"Data mean is: {data.mean:.2f}")
print(f"Standard Dev is: {data.std_dev:.2f}")
```

You can read more about their differences in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions).

Comment: yes, that works perfect, I have noticed that by using mean before was the cause of getting error, have no idea how avoid that when trying Std_dev. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Written following the issues stated in my comment on the OP as well as some generalized OOP practices, F-Strings and module import protection!

```
import math
import statistics as st


class Data:
    def __init__(self, d)
        self.d = d
        self.mean = st.mean(d)
        self.std_dev = st.stdev(d)

    def print_data():
        print(f"Data mean is: {data_1.mean:.2f}\nStandard Dev is: {data_1.std_dev:.2f}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_input = input("Enter data set:")
    data_1 = Data((float(x) for x in data_input.split(","))
    data_1.print_data()
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you actually runs that code gives the same error as in mine(not the post one) "Std Dev requires at least two data points", my guess is because it was used as mean.